# Slider HTML issue in Blogger

Tags: html, slider, blogger

So I have this new blog of mine, which contains a slider. ( you can take a look here : [Pc and Internet tutorials blog](http://pc-internet-tutorials.blogspot.com/)

As you can see in the slider there is actually no image being shown, its simply a white area behind the title and description in black wrapper.

The thing is in the slider part of html code everything is setup correct i guess

Here is the code if it would offer some help :

```
<b:if cond='data:blog.pageType != &quot;static_page&quot;'>
<b:if cond='data:blog.pageType != &quot;item&quot;'>

<script type='text/javascript'>
function startGallery() {
    var myGallery = new gallery($(&#39;myGallery&#39;), {
    timed: true,
    delay: 6000,
    slideInfoZoneOpacity: 0.8,
    showCarousel: false,
    slideInfoZoneSlide: false
});
}
window.addEvent(&#39;domready&#39;, startGallery);
</script>

<div class='fullbox_excerpt'>
    <div class='fullbox_content'>
        <div class='smooth_gallery'>
            <div id='myGallery'>

                <div class='imageElement'>
                    <h3>How to increase Facebook likes ?</h3>
                    <p>Getting likes on your status or picture on Facebook is probably an aim for every Facebook user. How not and everyone seeks that feeling of popularity through having many likes ?
                    In this tutorial I&#39;ll try to guide you step by step on how to increase the number of likes you get on Facebook.</p>
                    <a class='open' href='http://pc-internet-tutorials.blogspot.com.es/2014/08/how-to-get-facebook-likes.html' title='Get mroe Faceebook likes'/>
                    <img alt='get facebook likes on your picture' class='full' HEIGHT="50" WIDTH="50" src='http://1.bp.blogspot.com/-xTwClUYen3A/U_Hsap6QBdI/AAAAAAAAAMc/IGbxs0gIiz8/s1600/how-to-get-more-likes-facebook.jpg'/>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div></b:if></b:if>
```

http://pastebin.com/h2mkuHQT ( its a link because in this website it would get changed abit )

As you see the picture's urL you can find in the pastebin link is working, still picture isn't being shown.

any tips on how to fix this issue?

thanks in advance

Comment: You'll be wanting to add some code brother.

Comment: I'm new here sorry, but there is the code shown in the post now.

Answer (score 0):

You have an unclosed `<a>` tag that should be causing the problem.

update to:

```
            <div class="imageElement">
                <h3>How to increase Facebook likes ?</h3>
                <p>Getting likes on your status or picture on Facebook is probably an aim for every Facebook user. How not and everyone seeks that feeling of popularity through having many likes ?
                In this tutorial I'll try to guide you step by step on how to increase the number of likes you get on Facebook.</p>
                <a class="open" href="http://pc-internet-tutorials.blogspot.com.es/2014/08/how-to-get-facebook-likes.html" title="Get mroe Faceebook likes">
                    <img alt="get facebook likes on your picture" class="full" HEIGHT="50" WIDTH="50" src="http://1.bp.blogspot.com/-xTwClUYen3A/U_Hsap6QBdI/AAAAAAAAAMc/IGbxs0gIiz8/s1600/how-to-get-more-likes-facebook.jpg"/>
                </a>
            </div>
```

I believe this will help your problem.

You should not use self closed `<a>` tag if you want to use image (`<img>`) as anchor link.

Answer (score 0):

Allright, I have asked a friend, then problm was that in the CSS I had to add some code because currently the picture was there, just under the slider.

Adding this before the  tag solved the issue :

```
<style>div.slideElement { top: 0px; }</style>
```

thank you either way:)